# cannot download https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v3.13.1/darwin-x64-57_binding.node"

Tags: npm, node-gyp

I'm having difficulty installing some npm packages on my system. But not all.

I am working with WordPress template files, all of which use SASS for CSS, and all of which use their own set of packages to install. In some cases the installation has gone just fine. In others, not so much. The general pattern of the errors is consistent, but I'm not certain that the actual errors are.

In any event, this is the output from my attempt at just doing npm install. Can anyone pinpoint where things are going wrong, for me? I thought perhaps this was a problem with really old packages - and it still could be - but even relatively new themes suffer from the same problem.

Thanks in advance.

[My error log](https://gist.github.com/holisticnetworking/90199be0b8fd54f32316e9d8741f77d0)

Comment: Hi Thomas, are you sure the URL is correct? My browser reports **404** when I open https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v3.13.1/darwin-x64-57_binding.node

Answer (score 6):

the package **node-sass** is loading some files form Github at the end of npm install. Seems like at least one of these files `darwin-x64-57_binding.node` is no longer available for [v3.13.1](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/tag/v3.13.1).

Can you upgrade to the current version **node-sass@4.11.0**? This seems to have the `darwin-x64-57_binding.node` available.

Or you could see if you can fix the issue with **node-sass@3.13.1**. But there are lot's of warnings about outdated feature(s) in the log, so this could be tricky by now.

Does this help?

Comment: Every little bit helps, Konstantin! Here's a peep at my package.json file, which I should have included in the first place:

Comment: ```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "autoprefixer": ">6.3.6",
    "cssnano": ">3.7.0",
    "grunt": ">1.0.0",
    "grunt-browser-sync": ">2.2.0",
    "grunt-contrib-connect": ">1.0.2",
    "grunt-contrib-imagemin": ">1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": ">1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-sass": ">1.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": ">1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": ">1.0.0",
    "grunt-newer": ">1.2.0",
    "grunt-notify": ">0.4.1",
    "grunt-postcss": ">0.8.0",
    "grunt-svgmin": ">3.2.0",
    "pixrem": ">3.0.1",
    "sass-loader": ">6.0.7",
    "susy": ">3.0.3"
  }
}
'''

Comment: The character count on replies makes absolutely no sense.

Anyway, you can see I'm not loading node-sass directly. I guess I'll need to find an updated version of grunt-contrib-sass?

Comment: I was able to resolve this issue by just saving the package.json file as a bk and rebuilding with newer versions of stuff. Thanks @Konstintin!

Comment: Hi @ThomasBelknap, happy to see that you solved the issue. For NPM it makes no difference if you reference a package directly or indirectly (via dependencies): They still bekome part of your SW (tool chain in this case). _IF_ my answer concerning the versions was helpful, feel free to mark it as response. This marks the question as closed on SO.

Comment: Very similar problem I have raised it here but for different version https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/2811

Comment: Just did `npm install node-sass@4.11.0` and it works.

Answer (score 6):

I got a similar exception when switching computer and ran `npm install`. I simply removed `package-lock.json` and then it worked.

Answer (score 2):

I was using node 11.x version and I just downgrade my node version to 8.x. then it worked.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.11.0/darwin-x64-57_binding.node

Seems like your link is not valid I guess, give this link a try.

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed it using git bash (installed separately)
by running this command:

```
npm install --unsafe-perm -g node-sass
```

But I still need to understand why this error..
This link might help
https://nicedoc.io/sass/node-sass/blob/master/TROUBLESHOOTING.md

Answer (score 0):

If this issue is occuring in mac catalina OS. Then run these commands
If you have node-sass installed then uninstall it by running
`node-sass uninstall`

Then install node-sass by running `sudo npm install --unsafe-perm -g node-sass`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when I was running npm install. I resolve it by editing the package.json file and updating gulp-sass to version 3.0.0

```
"gulp-sass": "^3.0.0"
```